# Why does my bound button, goes unpressed itself?

Tags: android, android-databinding, pressed

I made a button and bound it's `pressed` state to some observable.

In sample below, observable is just constant.

Nevrtheless, this button goes unpressed either after some time itself, or after application switch

[image]

Activity code is follows:

```
public class TryResearchButtonUnpress extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_try_research_button_unpress);
        ActivityTryResearchButtonUnpressBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_try_research_button_unpress);
        binding.setActivity(this);
    }

    public final ObservableBoolean pressed = new ObservableBoolean(true);
}
```

layout code is follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="activity" type="com.inthemoon.tryresearchbuttonunpress.TryResearchButtonUnpress"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@+id/activity_try_research_button_unpress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:pressed="@{activity.pressed}"
            android:src="@drawable/record_selector"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Resources and full code are in GitHub: https://github.com/dims12/TryResearchButtonUnpress

I suspect this is because I bound values to the view itself. This was nowhere described, but I tried it on my own risk.

**UPDATE**

I have put the observable into separate class, but button is unpressing nevertheless.

See [github commit 690fbee](https://github.com/dims12/TryResearchButtonUnpress/tree/690fbee7cd733eb59afc6e5e4f206479980f2ade).

**UPDATE 2**

I was unable to set "bidirectional binding" with the following code

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:pressed="@={model.pressed}"
            android:src="@drawable/record_selector"
            />
```

due to the following error

> Error:(8, 58) error: package
>   com.inthemoon.tryresearchbuttonunpress.databinding does not exist
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
> >     ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:pressed' with value type boolean on
> >     android.widget.ImageButton.
> >     file:D:\Users\Dims\Design\TryResearchButtonUnpress\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_try_research_button_unpress.xml
> >     loc:18:8 - 24:13
> >     ****\ data binding error ****

Comment: your problem is that you're not following the MVVM pattern correctly. you need to separete the ViewModel from the View and the Model. This means that the activity onCreate() is creating the Model every time, and if you do a rotation for example it will change the state because the model is recreated

Comment: @SergioLima But the model has `pressed == true` constant, even if model is recreated, it should be `true`. How can it turn `false` even if recreated?

Answer (score 0):

Button - this is UI component, which provide feedback. I think you need create [two-way databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33474455/3926506) to recive and store pressed (unpressed) state. I.e.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"

    android:pressed="@={activity.pressed}"

    android:src="@drawable/record_selector"/>
```

Next, you need to implement [`@InverseBindingAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter.html) for reverse binding from view:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:pressed")
public static boolean getPressedState(ImageButton button){
    return button.isPressed();
}
```

Also, you need to save button state using override of `onSaveInstanceState()` menhod and restore it in override of `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: See my `Update 2` please.

Comment: @Dims, you need to implement `@InverseBindingAdapter`

Comment: So many glue code!!! Not looks like "binding" anymore; I would call it "mounting" or "establishing"...

Comment: How else. You need to define rules for sending custom data into view and take custom data back. By the way, data type may be different.

Comment: The problem is that it works partially. For example, it sucessfully transfers "pressed" state from property to view. So, the `getPressedState` method you suggest is definitely redundant, because it does what already works.

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure if the twoway binding works , because i never used it (tried but never worked)
So the workaround is to

```
<Button
      ...
      android:onClick="@{activity.onClicked}"/>
```

and on the activity (which is working as your ViewModel)

have a method

```
public void onCliked(Button view){
   // update datamodel pressed state
   model.setPressed(view.isPressed());
}
```

//Disclaimer .. this is just pseudo code, the idea is this